# Functionality to auto pick up the call using expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo, call, pickup

As part of a project I'm developing an application for the care of people with cognitive disorders, it may happen that such a person forgets where he put his phone. Therefore, it needs functionality that will allow the phone to be automatically answered when a trusted number calls. I don't know what I could use to create such functionality.

I create the application using expo-react-native. I tried to use the expo-phone-call library, but I can't install it because it shows an error that such a library doesn't exist. On the other hand, when trying to use react-native-phone-call, I kept getting errors with importing things.

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting while importing react-native-phone-call ?

Comment: Can you this snack as reference - https://snack.expo.dev/@aboutreact/example-to-call-from-app-in-react-native?platform=ios

Comment: @ElenaAlexeenko every time I am getting the error that eventListener does not exist

Answer (score 0):

There's no straightforward way to initiate an automatic call or make a call inside the application using Expo. Expo is designed to be a secure environment, so it doesn't allow certain types of direct system access without user interaction.